# Using R shiny server for controlling cyclic execution in while loop

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a simple app that will do the following in a loop:
0. wait for the start button
1. system call to create a screenshot and save it to disk
2. render the screenshot from disk to shiny output
3. print status "filename - ok" 
4. Sys.sleep for e.g. 5sec
5. Check if the stop button is not activated - go to 1.

This idea in code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("My App"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            radioButtons("control", h3("Start/Stop switch"),
                         choices = list("Start" = TRUE, 
                                        "Stop" = FALSE
                         ),selected = TRUE),
            actionButton("go", label = "Go!")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            textOutput("status"),
            imageOutput("image")
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
    actionflag <- eventReactive(input$go,{input$control})
    while (actionflag()==TRUE) {
        fname<-gsub("[[:punct:] ]", "", Sys.time())
        system(paste0("screencapture -t jpg -x ~/Documents/Screens/", fname,".jpg"))
        output$status <- renderText({paste(fname,"screen captured")})
        output$image <- renderImage({
            list(src = paste0("~/Documents/Screens/",fname,".jpg"),
                 alt = "Image",
                 width = 400,
                 height = 300)
        }, deleteFile = FALSE)
        Sys.sleep(5)
    }
}
```

But it does not work this way. Formally I get this error:
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Moreover, even without control buttons (while(1==1){execute code}), I was not able to use while loop in shiny server to continuously change the output. I guess this 'while' implementation is totally wrong, so any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a shiny app with 2 buttons (go and stop). When 'go' is pressed a screenshot is taken every 5 seconds and rendered in the UI. The 'looping' occurs by observing a [reactiveValue](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.12.1/reactiveValues.html) we can create in the server in this example called 'rv$loop'.  The 'go' button always makes 'rv$loop' 1 and the 'stop' button always makes 'rv$loop' -100.  If 'rv$loop' is > 0 the code will execute and continuously run by always adding 1 to'rv$loop' at the end of the observer which re-triggers the start.

Additionally, the [shinyjs](https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/) package function ['delay'](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/delay.html) allows for time-delays before the execution of a line of code without putting the whole R session to sleep allowing for the new screenshot to be loaded into the browser. To use shinyjs the line 'useShinyJs()' needs to be dropped somewhere in the UI code.

Usually shiny apps can only access certain folders contained in their app's directory that it knows to look and is by default launched with the app like a 'www' folder for static images/logos/etc. To add a folder as a resource folder you need to use '[addResourePath](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/resourcePaths.html)' to make the '~/Documents/Screens' available to the app when it is launched.

This example app will only work id there is a '~/Documents/Screens' directory on your machine. Uncomment the first few line to create this directory if needed.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

#make sure this directory exists
#uncomment and run if there is no 'Screens' folder in your 'Documents'
# if(!file.exists("~/Documents/Screens")){
#   dir.create("~/Documents/Screens")
# }

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(), #make sure to drop this useShinyJs line somewhere in UI
  actionButton("go", label = "Go!"),
  actionButton("stop", label = "Stop!"),
  textOutput('status'),
  uiOutput("image")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #allow shiny app to access files in this non-shiny app directory folder
  addResourcePath("screen", "~/Documents/Screens")

  #this reactive value rv$loop will serve as our loop starter/stopper
  rv <- reactiveValues(loop = 0)

  #if input go is clicked the loop is started 
  #because the observe event only continues if rv$loop is > 0
  observeEvent(input$go,{
    rv$loop <- 1
  })

  #if input stop is clicked loop is stopped
  #because this makes rv$loop -100, which is < 0 
  #so observe event is not triggered again for the screenshot loop

  observeEvent(input$stop,{
    rv$loop <- -100
  })

  #observe changes in the rv$loop variable
  #only do anything if the rv$loop value is greater than 0
  #if it is triggered the last line adds 1 to rv$loop
  #which re-validates the observeEvent to trigger it again
  #it only stops if input$stop is pushed to make rv$loop -100
   observeEvent(rv$loop, {
     if(rv$loop > 0){
     #add the name of file to a reactive value to access inside/outside of this observe event
     rv$name <- gsub("[[:punct:] ]", "", Sys.time())
     system(paste0("screencapture -t jpg -x ~/Documents/Screens/", rv$name,".jpg"))
     #use shinyjs function 'delay' to wait to add 1
     #or Sys.sleep put everything to sleep and the app 
     #would not load the imaged because it was asleep an
     #did not have enough time. 
     shinyjs::delay(5000, rv$loop <- rv$loop + 1)
     }
   })

output$status <- renderText({paste(rv$name,"screen captured")})
output$image <- renderUI({
  img(src = paste0('screen/', rv$name, '.jpg'))
})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

P.S. - I never knew you could screenshot like this and I thought it was pretty neat.

[image]